# apache error log doesn't print custom data

Tags: python, apache, flask

( Before Question begins, My English is not good. sorry ;( )

I am developing an application based on flask using apache

The Question is why custom data doesn't print in error log?

for example

```
@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def time_():
    print 2
    return json.dumps({'test':'test'})
```

access log is working('test' printed on my website), but error log doesn't print 2

ps. I already restart httpd

Comment: `print` cannot be used to log into files.You need to use something like `logging.info('2')` . See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)

Comment: Yes. you need to log it. In fact you can log using flask. `from flask import current_app; current_app.logger.info('2')`